# 'sumif' or calculate/sum for values in the same column power BI

Tags: powerbi

I've got a sum within a spreadsheet which I need to create within a powerBI table but I am completely stumped at the moment as to how I might create it as I am quite new to the program.

the sum within excel is as follows `SUMIFS($X:$X,$J:$J,"Y",$AS:$AS,$AO47)`

this seems simple enough however the sum range X:X is the same as the column X with the formula the values in columns AS & AO mean that it doesn't create a circular reference.

in power BI the column names translate as follows:

```
X = Spli

J = BLD

AS = NotID

AO = CRef
```

as far as I can see it's just not an option to use calculate/Sum and refer to the same column... I'm unsure if there would be a workaround for this that I'm just not seeing.

Hopefully someone can help! :)

Comment: It's very hard to help you with the info provided. Could you instead provide your data sample, and an example of the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your issue correct, you can use either **CALCULATE** or **SUMX** for your **Measure** as stated below-

Using **CALCULATE**-

```
_sum =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[column_name]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[filter_column_name_1] = 1
        && your_table_name[filter_column_name_2] = "ABC"
    )
)
```

Using **SUMX**-

```
_sum =
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[filter_column_name_1] = 1
        && your_table_name[filter_column_name_2] = "ABC"
    ), 
    your_table_name[column_name]
)
```